# How to show WKWebView on half the page with label and buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am new to Xcode and app development in general, and am a senior in high school and am making an app for my senior project.  I have a view controller and I need to show a website on the bottom half of the screen and have a label and button above the website.  Using the example code that apple gives in their Developer Documentation about WKWeb View I am able to load the website, but it takes up the full screen.  Is there a way to make it so the webpage only takes up half of the screen. I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to do this, but if anyone knows of one that would help.

````
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .init(), configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       let myURL = URL(string:"http://example.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }




} ```
````

Comment: In your storyboard where you have added your webview. Just set the constraints so that the webview takes up the space that you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here: view = webView.
Here you assign your webView to be the rootView of your ViewController, which usually is the whole screen (at least in your case).

You better ADD it to your view.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

private var webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the delegate for webView
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    // define URL
    let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com/de/")

    // create request
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

    // show request
    webView.load(myRequest)

    // make webView ready for Autolayout
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // add webView to view
    view.addSubview(webView)

    // size the webView beeing 75 % of the screen
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
    }    
}
```

Comment: I tried the same, it caused like an infinite loop when trying to add webView using addSubView method. It makes the app crashes.